# Ubuntu 18.04: Missing Problem Reporting option in Privacy Settings

Tags: 18.04, settings, privacy

I am missing the Problem Reporting option in Privacy Settings, and I wanted to set it as manual. It was there when I installed Ubuntu, but now it's gone.

To clarify, I have Ubuntu 18.04 with the Pop theme and icons. The Problem Reporting option was there even after installing that theme.

Literally the only thing I did after a fresh install was following some of the steps in the following links; on one of the reboots, the option was gone forever.

- [Things to do After Installing Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04/)
- [How to Install Themes in Ubuntu 18.04 and 17.10 - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-ubuntu/)
- [How to Use GNOME Shell Extensions [Complete Guide] - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/)

[image: Settings Screenshot]

How can I get that option back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How this would have happened or **methods to reproduce** the problem.

- Add Pop!_OS repository using:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
  ```
- Upgrade the system or upgrade/reinstall gnome-control-center. Use:

  ```
  sudo apt upgrade
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-control-center
  ```

### What happened?

In my understanding the unofficial derivatives of Ubuntu like Pop!_OS remove options of bug reporting because they don't want their users to report bugs in Pop!_OS directly to Canonical (this is quite obvious since Canonical is not responsible for fixing their bugs) and they might haven't created the bug reporting mechanism for themselves (at least via their distribution)(if they have I don't know since I don't use Pop!_OS).

So, after adding repository of Pop!_OS, Ubuntu thinks the added repository has an **updated** version of gnome-control-center, that's why when upgraded, it uses Pop!_OS's repository, downloads and replaces the default version **1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2** with **1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2pop0** of gnome-control-center and install 2-3 more packages. Clearly the latter looks like a modified version and thus doesn't have ***Problem Reporting*** option under ***Privacy***

### What to do?

The only workaround I think is remove Pop!_OS's repository and reinstall gnome-control-center

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:system76/pop
sudo apt autoremove gnome-control-center
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

**Note:** Don't use `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center` since I got an error like *Reinstallation of gnome-control-center is not possible, it cannot be downloaded*. Moreover packages installed via Pop!_OS's repository will be there even after removing repository unless explicitly removed. So don't worry about icons and themes, you can still use that.

Comment: Alright! So it actually is a Pop theme problem! It is strange, since I actually still saw that option after installing the theme... I guess it only disappeared after an upgrade/reboot. So this means it is "supposed to be like that" with the Pop theme right? And can only keep such option with default themes?

Answer (score 3):

Try to sanitize apt cache.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

Then try to purge and reinstall fixing broken and missing packages.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt purge -y gnome-control-center && sudo apt install -y --install-recommends --fix-broken --fix-missing gnome-control-center
```

Comment: The commands run with no errors, but the Problem Reporting option is still missing from my settings... I literally just followed some of the steps in the following links after a fresh install (I have Ubuntu 18.04 with the Pop theme): 1- https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04/ 2- https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-ubuntu/ 3- https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/