# Why is my Ubuntu 18.04 distribution asking me to upgrade to Pop!_OS 19.10?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, notification

[image: Message to upgrade to Pop!_OS from Ubuntu]I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I just received a notification that I can upgrade to Pop!_OS 19.10. Why in the world would this happen? Did I break my system? Has anyone else had something similar happen?

The only thing I have installed from Pop!_OS is their icon theme. Could it be because I have their ppa on my system? How can I clear this notification and request to update?

Comment: Go to `Software & Updates`, track their ppa and disable them.

Comment: My guess is you've polluted your sources with Pop!_OS ones, so I'd check your sources.  `apt` and package tools upgrade to the latest tools, and downstream OSes use this to ensure their packages get used; thus downstream sources can cause an upstream OS to become polluted when added.  *You're likely only seeing a text message; I'd `fgrep` and find it, then `dpkg -S` to find what package introduced that onto your system*

Comment: @Jim I have tracked the ppa that is system76/pop/** This seems to have made the message disappear.

Comment: @guiverc I do not understand. I posted a picture that shows the message in my update software center. If it is just a text message where exactly do I use `fgrep`? And how can that then be used with `dpkg -S` in order to find the package that caused the problem?

Comment: That's good, the message seems to be caused by pop os `ppa`.

Comment: @Jim actually, the option to upgrade still exists in my about page as previously depicted. Other than that one icon repository, I have no explicit ties to system76 or pop os. I looked at this via the synaptic package manager. No idea where to go from here.

Comment: It's a silly question— but have you tried restarting the system, and check again if it is gone ?

Comment: @Jim Yeah, sadly that did nothing for me.

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu 18.04: Missing Problem Reporting option in Privacy Settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/1103531/816190)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I figured out what the issue is after some detective work and some experimentation. I had the Pop! ppa on my system for some reason. I guess this was a side effect of using the Pop Icon theme. I was searching through folders in `/var/lib/` and found an empty `pop-upgrade` folder. At first I was not certain what it was, but it was entirely too coincidental for me to have a Pop!_OS system upgrade message and run across this folder and not have them be connected.

I have TimeShift on a daily schedule (highly recommend this people) so I decided to just `sudo apt-get remove pop-upgrade` and see what happened. I did this and then used `autoremove` but I ran into issues. I no longer had an ability to get to my default Gnome `Settings` menu. There were probably a bunch of other issues.

So what I did was I used TimeShift to go back to the day before, and when I went to `apt-get upgrade` I realized that `gnome-control-center` was being held back from upgrading because it needed additional packages. Those packages were `libpop-upgrade` and something else. So now I had it cornered. I must have used `dist-upgrade` earlier that night without realizing it, and it just force installed those extra Pop! packages, which led to the message. After I removed the Pop! ppa from my sources list, `gnome-control-center` no longer wanted to update, and `pop-upgrade` was not requesting an install.

Basically, **do not have Pop! ppa on your Ubuntu system**, because it will cause problems. I should have seen this coming but I am still only an intermediate with Linux. If you have already run into this same problem I had above, roll back to a previous point in time before the `gnome-control-center` upgrade, and remove the Pop! ppa from your system. Then you should be able to use `update` and `upgrade` without contaminating your system.

Comment: I did `sudo apt remove --autoremove pop-upgrade` and then `sudo apt install gnome-control-center` and I got settings menu back.

Answer (score 32):

By adding the Pop PPA, you've received the patched version of GNOME Control Center, which pulls in pop-upgrade, which will prompt to upgrade to Pop!_OS 19.10. It's a required dependency of the patched version of gnome-control-center, so removing it would also remove the control center. We don't recommend adding the Pop! ppa on top of Ubuntu. We apologize for the issues it caused!

Comment: Thanks, after doing some detective work late last night I realized that this was the cause of the issue. Removing the pop-upgrade from my system also caused huge problems, but that could've been my fault. After I removed it, I no longer had a settings app and other oddities. I used Time Shift to go back, remove the Pop! ppa, and then upgraded without issues. Thanks for your feedback though Emma, much appreciated.

Comment: How do you recommend fixing such a situation?

Comment: @nealmcb Read my other answer I will soon mark as a solution. In order to remedy the situation, I could *not* just remove the pop-upgrade package. Doing so caused a bunch of other problems. The simplest solution I found was to roll back using TimeShift to a point where I had not installed the newest version of control center, and then remove the system76/pop ppa, then upgrade as normal. It's important to be careful when using `dist-upgrade` or `upgrade --with-new-pkgs` because this is how the pop-upgrade problem ended up on my system. Always read what the results of your command will be.

Comment: Thank you, @bmcentee148, and I am glad you found a solution and documented it, with tips for avoiding the situation! But not everyone has such good backups, so I am still hoping that Emma and the Pop! OS supporters provide robust instructions for other common situations.

Comment: The PPA now seems to have a warning [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/pop) as well as while adding repository. The warning states: *This PPA is for Pop!_OS, and it may cause breakage on other Ubuntu-based OS's. Use of this repository on non-Pop_OS installations is at your own risk!*