# System settings won't open on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after adding System76/pop PPA

Tags: 20.04, ppa, system-settings, gnome-control-center

I'm trying to open System Settings but it won't open in any way.
Using GUI, Settings are trying to load for a moment and then they are gone.
Using Terminal (`gnome-control-center`), I get:

```
(gnome-control-center:8823): GLib-ERROR **: 14:44:15.433: ../../../glib/gmem.c:138: failed to allocate 13477064712 bytes
Trap Trace/breakpoint (core dumped)
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

With multiple reboots, but I had no result.

---

**UPDATE!**: Same errors persist **BUT**, when I type:

```
sudo gnome-control-center
```

(instead of just "gnome-control-center") suddenly System Settings appear! Is it a user permissions issue? Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE#2**: After some system updates, `sudo gnome-control-center` now spawns "*Segmentation fault*".

Comment: it may be related to this bug https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/342
However try this `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center`

Comment: Does this help?  https://forum.level1techs.com/t/settings-wont-launch-gnome-control-center/142034/12

Comment: @kenn doesn't work. It spawns the same error.

Comment: @Ollie I installed hidpi-daemon but still, I get the same error when I'm trying to open system settings.

Comment: getting the same issue.  not sure if anyone else has been getting this but i've noticed my online accounts were not longer signed in.  i signed back in but see no option for them in Files.

Comment: Did you get this remedied?

Comment: Had sort of same issue where I got the error "error while loading shared libraries: libpop_upgrade_gtk.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" on using gnome-control-center. Issues started when I updated gnome settings from Pop shop and then system settings was not loading from gui and cmd.
Tried purge removing control center and was unable to install, got some dependency errors. Got it fixed after following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353379/cant-install-gnome-control-center-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found a solution!
The cause of this problem was pop-theme, that I installed once, plus its repository entry, that provided me the broken System settings (`gnome-control-center`). In order to solve this:

1. I installed Ubuntu desktop PPA.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa
   ```
2. I removed all **System76/pop** (and other trush) entries, with `update-manager`, **leaving Ubuntu desktop the only one active**.
   [image: update-manager]
3. Now that I have the proper repository entry added, I re-install `gnome-control-center`.

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
   ```
4. Enjoy Gnome System settings!

Comment: System76's employee themselves [don't recommend](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188837/) using Pop!_OS' PPA over Ubuntu.

Comment: I didn't have System76/pop at all, but following your procedure resolved the problem for me. All I removed was the entry for WineHQ.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix by removing the GNOME extension/theme which caused the issue and then running:

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Just reinstalling gnome-control-center didn't solve my problem. I had resolve the repository issue (as seen on my and @nobody 's solution).

Comment: This is the right answer. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

For the next step the PPA has to be active.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop
```

This removes packages from this PPA if they are not available from Ubuntu repositories, or reverts to Ubuntu package versions.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... a variant of this:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- No Pop!_OS' PPA - present.
- `sudo gnome-control-center` # worked, from a terminal/shell,
  but not so **without 'sudo'**, no `GLib-ERROR`, with no output at all.
- "Ubuntu software" - also affected, didn't try 'sudo' there though.
- `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/` didn't appear to help.
- Neither did the apt --reinstall below.

Remedy:

- Reboot into "recovery console"
  *hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> ONCE after the BIOS displays to get to the boot*
  menu)
- run the "dpkg" option to install / fix packages
  *this brought in a gcc1* -thingie, didn't pay attention to exactly what*
- also run fsck option
- enable networking
- drop to root prompt,
  *press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> one extra time at the extra prompt*
- run:

```
$ apt-get install -f --reinstall gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data
$ reboot
```

**Note:**
Remedy worked only as it was run **in recovery mode**.

Comment: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/` worked for me

Comment: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/` is what worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was resetting all configurations of the control-center with the following command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/
```

This works until I click on "*Display*" in "*System Settings*".  Then it stops working and I need to run the command again.

This was tested on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (x86_64).

Comment: it worked but when I click on display in settings System settings are closed and i had to run reset `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center`  command again. basically you do not click on Display in System setting.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I suggested or @nobody 's solution?

Comment: Yes I tried every solution we have here. nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue on 20.04. I clearly remember at the time of Ubuntu installation system settings was working perfectly, but out of nowhere this problem arose. What i did:

1. Reset the gnome-control-center by
   `sudo dconf reset -f /org/gnome-control-center` (but the problem didn’t go away).
2. Then I tried to access settings through the terminal by typing
   `gnome-control-center`, but it said I don’t have this installed.
3. After installing gnome-control-center by `sudo apt install gnome-control-center` I rebooted and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and looking at the question and answers here, I checked `gnome-control-center` in the terminal and it was not installed. Installing it solved the problem. I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-control-center is not able to load if any of key is not found. kindly run below commands.

```
sudo rm -rfv /home/kali/.config/dconf
sudo apt install gnome-control-center --reinstall
```

Now check the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself coming back here every now and then, you can always make a shell script to make your life easier:

```
nano ~/Desktop/settings-fix
```

`Ctrl`+`C` this:

```
echo "You again  !?";
echo "Alright, lemme fix that for you  !";
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center;
echo "You're good to go ";
echo "More here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245159/system-settings-wont-open-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-adding-system76-pop-ppa";
```

`Ctrl`+`Shift` + `V` it in the text editor

`Ctrl`+`Shift` + `O` to save

`Ctrl`+`Shift` + `X` to close the editor

In your terminal:

`chmod 744 ./Desktop/settings-fix`

`sudo cp ~/Desktop/settings-fix /usr/bin`

Now whenever you run to this again, you can simply run from your terminal:

```
settings-fix
```

Comment: Just reinstalling gnome control center didn't solve the problem but... I like the way you think. :)