# Getting error while installing Pop OS [Ubuntu to Pop OS]

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, repository

I am getting errors while installing Pop Os from Ubuntu.

Error while adding repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
```

404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

```
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/enso-os/panther-launcher/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Error while updating `sudo apt update`

```
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/enso-os/panther-launcher/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/enso-os/panther-launcher/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Error while installing `sudo apt install pop-desktop`.

```
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/vendor.conf', which is also i
n package gnome-initial-setup 3.36.2-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1593716052~20.04~e07a263
_amd64.deb
```

What's the solution???

Comment: Yupp. The solution was there but in a different way. Thanks

Comment: PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu does not support *focal*.  PPA's are 3rd party sources, so all checks are your responsibility (are they maintained, trusthworthy etc).  Did you perform the required checks (esp. if security matters to you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. The solution is `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1593716052~20.04~e07a263 _amd64.deb`

Comment: Thanks dude it worked. Forcing to overwrite is the solution

Comment: But during an update you get same problem with the involved packages. Better is to remove one of the package. and for futher problems https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245159/system-settings-wont-open-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-adding-system76-pop-ppa/1266235#1266235