# Can't Install Gnome-Control-Center on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, package-management, software-center, dependencies, gnome-control-center

I installed xfce4 on my ubuntu today i removed it and installed Gnome back, but after that i had issues where my setting was not able to open i searched about it and found that `gnome-control-center` was missing from my computer and i then tried to install it and got this error

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: gnome-control-center-data (< 1:3.37) but 1:3.38.3-1pop1~1625337172~20.04~bdcf8ad is to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-control-center-faces but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea how can i fix it ?

Edit:
After running the command `sudo apt-cache policy gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center` i got this output:

```
gnome-control-center-data:
  Installed: 1:3.38.3-1pop1~1625337172~20.04~bdcf8ad
  Candidate: 1:3.38.3-1pop1~1625337172~20.04~bdcf8ad
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.38.3-1pop1~1625337172~20.04~bdcf8ad 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
     1:3.36.1-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
gnome-control-center:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.36.1-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Thanks To @N0rbert I realised i had `gnome-control-center-data` installed which was for `1:3.38.3-1pop1~1625337172~20.04~bdcf8ad` and i just remove it using `sudo apt remove gnome-control-center-data` and then just reinstalled it using `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center` and everything worked fine

Comment: Are you running PopOS? What is the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center` ?

Comment: @N0rbert I have edited the question with adding the output of your command please check this, and also i had installed Pop Icon theme which i later remove, and also when i boot my system it says "System76 powermanager Failed" something like that but still it boots up

Comment: For sure please also add output of `dpkg -l | grep pop` . Do you use System76 hardware?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Package is from https://answers.launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/proposed/+index?field.series_filter=focal ; for use by Pop!_OS and not Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install GNOME Control Center you have to specify its version manually by using command below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data=3.36.5-0ubuntu2
```

to avoid conflict with previously installed *3.38.3-1pop1~1625337172~20.04~bdcf8ad* version.

---

To correctly remove all trails of PopOS!, you have to re-add [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esystem76/+archive/ubuntu/pop?field.series_filter=focal) and then purge it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop
```

Comment: Thanks alot brother! it Just Worked!!!!